# High contrast image filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image-processing

I need a way to achive this effect
[image]

The top photo is what is going to be the input. I have tried and it doesn't seem to be posible using any of the web-filters, the the solution will probobly we to use a canvas. The problem is just that i have to experiance in using a canvas. 
Also, would it be possible for the user to interact with the contrast using a slider?

The image will be inputted through a link that is simply called `url`.

Comment: CamanJS can be used for canvas manipulation. http://camanjs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there's some constraint that I can't see, you shouldn't need to use canvas. You can do this by combining the grayscale and contrast filters in CSS like this:

`img {
  filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(10000%);
}`

Moving `contrast` above 100% allows you to achieve high contrast, whereas 100% is the natural contrast of the image. The number used here is just an arbitrarily large value. You can test and see what will work best for you.

Here's a pen of your image to demonstrate:

http://codepen.io/denmch/pen/b20ef5302b9f64fd8c5a82e49ab2f980

Updating values is possible with JS, but is a little more advanced. You can see something similar in this pen, where the values for things like image blur can be modified with a slider:

http://codepen.io/denmch/pen/MbqWEb

This was based on the third lesson in Wes Bos's free JavaScript 30 course:

https://javascript30.com/

That'd be a good place to get started on how to manipulate values like these.